# How can I create a script to allow a user to add new rows (by providing prompts to the user) to a table in Oracle 10g?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is some of the code that I have tried and failed with. First attempt:

```
UPDATE criminals 
set criminal_id = '&criminal_id'
set "last" = '&last'
set "first" = '&first'
set street = '&street'
set city = '&city'
set state = '&state'
set zip = '&zip'
set phone = '&phone';enter code here
```

Second attempt:

```
INSERT INTO criminals (&criminal_id, &last, &first, &street, &city, &state, &zip, &phone);
```

Third attempt:

```
INSERT INTO criminals  
VALUES (set criminal_id = '&criminal_id'  
        set "last" = '&last' 
        set "first" = '&first'  
        set street = '&street'  
        set city = '&city'  
        set state = '&state'  
        set zip = '&zip'  
        set phone = '&phone');
```

My 1,000,000 other attempts were just variations on these themes. I know it's relatively simple, but I'm brand spanking new to database design and Oracle, and I humbly request your help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me.

INSERT INTO Criminals
VALUES ('&Criminal_ID', '&Last', '&First', '&Street', '&City','&State','&Zip', '&Phone', '&v_status', '&p_status');

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much!